# Resource Timeline: Events function only called when pressing prev or next button but not when scrolling through the timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I use the FullCalendar React Component with the resource timeline view. My goal is to fetch only events for the area the user is actually able to see. Because of structure of my API I cannot provide a JSON feed. So according to the docs there is events as a function. I started to implement a solution for this approach but the problem is, the function is only called when I actually press a button for next or previous but not when I just scroll through the timeline, but that is what I would actually need. Is this achievable with Fullcalendar? To make it as easy as possible for you to reproduce this behaviour here is the component I have implemented:

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';

function App() {
  return (
    <FullCalendar
        plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin ]}
        initialView="resourceTimelineYear"
        schedulerLicenseKey = "CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives"
        resources={
          [
            {id: "a",title: "Room A"},
            {id: "b",title: "Room B"},
            {id: 'c',title: 'Room C'}
          ]
        }
        events={
          function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            console.log("Call!"); /* only called when prev. or next button is 
            pressed but not when scrolling through the timeline */
          }
        }
        height={650}
      />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `Is this achievable with Fullcalendar`...no because it's impossible for the calendar to know what is currently visible on the screen. It doesn't know the width of the calendar at that exact moment (and what if you change the size of the viewport during use?) and therefore what is/isn't visible. It could also lead to lots of unnecessary requests too, potentially. It will fetch events for the start and end dates defined. You seem to have specified a whole year. If you aren't going to display the whole year at once easily, then maybe define the view as a month or 3-month period instead?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for that fast answer. So now that I know it cannot be done through scrolling my option will be that the user uses the prev. and next buttons for navigation in order to work with proper event fetching as a function, right? So every time he would press one of those buttons my function would be called and the events for the specified timespan inside fetchInfo would be put into the calendar. Is my understanding here correct?

Comment: yes that's right. If it was me, I would set a smaller time period for the view (e.g. 1 month, or 3 months maybe, as I mentioned) and then the user can use next/prev to navigate further ahead or further back. That will then cause the events function to run and request new events each time they navigate to a time period for which events have not already been downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, a month to view seems reasonable to me. It's a bit sad from the users point of view that this can't be done via scrolling, but as you mentioned in your first post, if it could be done it would be really complex. So I will go with solution approach you advised. Thanks again for the fast and really helpful explanations here.